# Uses undefined class/has incomplete type

Tags: c++

```
class a;
class b;

class a {
    b c;
};

class b {
};
```

Why doesn't this compile? I was under the impression that if you declared prototypes of classes, it didn't matter in which order they were declared. However, this doesn't work. In visual studio, it gives me:

```
error C2079: 'a::c' uses undefined class 'b'
```

In g++, it gives me:

```
error: field 'c' has incomplete type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It **does** matter what order classes are defined in.  Definitions must be available before by-value use.

Comment: It would probably work as you expect if `c` was a `b*` (pointer)

Comment: Oli, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6188095/2159051 it says literally "any order will do". And what is the purpose of prototypes then?

Comment: trojansdestroy okay I tried it, and you are right. Why is that? What if I want an instance of it, not a pointer?

Comment: In that answer, all classes are prototyped, so the order of definitions doesn't matter. However, those definitions don't show any content. You can't have a member of class that hasn't been defined yet; however, you can have a member that is a pointer to an undefined class. See the next answer on your linked question.

Comment: If you want an instance of `b`, you have to *define* (not just declare) `class b` before `class a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler sees

```
class a {
  b c;
};
```

it knows that `b` exist, but it doesn't know what it is (hence, it doesn't know how much space it will require, hence it doesn't know how to build `a`)

However what you could do is using a pointer on `b`:

```
class a {
  b* c;
};
```

---

Edit:

It means you won't be able to manipulate a `b` before it is defined. E.g: you **can't do**:

```
class a {
  b* c;
  void f(){
    c->doSomething(); // <- Won't compile
  }

};
```

What you **can do** is separating `a` definition in a `.hh` and `.cc`:

in a.hh

```
class b; //Say it exists. Don't say what it looks like

class a {
  b* c;
  void f();
};
```

in a.cc

```
#include "b.hh" //now it's ok to use b.hh: it won't yield a circular reference because b.hh may include a.hh but it doesn't include a.cc

void a::f(){
  c->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Okay this is a good answer. This makes sense. So this means there is no way to have an instance of something before it is defined?

Comment: You can have an instance if you're called with one, but you won't be able to do much with it... I just edited my answer to provide the solution.

Comment: Hmm. This does answer my question. Accepted. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the time `a` uses `b` it has been declared (because you wrote `class b;` above it) but not defined (the definition is below `a`). "Incomplete Type" means the type has been declared but not defined.